# Migrating Discourse user to Django user

Tags: django, discourse

I have exported database from Discourse. it does contain password_hash and salt.

I have done my research and found out that Django uses `PBKDF2` by default and even [Discours use that with hashing algorithm sha256 and number of iterations 64000](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/docs/SECURITY.md#password-storage).

I want to migrate those password so that Django will be able to authenticate a user with the same password.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways you could do this.

Write your own authentication method in the backend - which accepts the same hashing method as Discourse when a user attempts to login. This way the hashed password should match from the user's salt and the password they have entered.

This can be done as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import PBKDF2PasswordHasher

class MyPBKDF2PasswordHasher(PBKDF2PasswordHasher):
    """
    A subclass of PBKDF2PasswordHasher that uses 64000 times more iterations.
    """
    iterations = PBKDF2PasswordHasher.iterations * n
    iterations = 64000 #Use this for simplicity!!
```

in `hashers.py`. Please note - `PBKDF2PasswordHasher.iterations * n` will have to equal 64000 - I think the number of iterations is currently set to `150000`, so probably easier to have `iterations = 64000` directly. The iterations is all you're looking to change, and all other behaviour will be inherited from the `PBKDF2PasswordHasher` Class.

Then, all you will need is:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'application_name.hashers.MyPBKDF2PasswordHasher',
]
```

in `settings.py`, where `application_name` is, *yep you guessed it*, the name of the application where `hashers.py` can be found.

However...the following documentation on storage and hashing of passwords may be extremely useful in your search:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/#auth-password-storage